# M2 extension manager keep spinning

Tags: magento2.3.4

I'm trying to install an extension with Web Setup Wizard but after clicking Extention Manager the mouse keep spinning with a Please wait statement and hang.

Comment: Something must throwing an js error. Check your console.

Comment: Do you mean console.log??